# Hataras Nederim Erev Rosh HaShanah

Tags: sources-mekorot, rosh-hashanah-new-year, nedarim-shevuot

What is the earliest makor (source) for making hataras nederim erev rosh hashanah in front of 3 people with a long nusach? It appears from minimal research to be a rather "late" minhag. What is the first source that one should perform this? Also is it a "chiyuv" (requirement) for one to do or just a nice thing or custom?